# How can I add 1 to a generic T?

Tags: rust

Below is a generic type `Foo`. How can I correctly implement the `addOne` method:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    n: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn addOne(self) -> T {
        self.n + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo { n: 5 };
    println!("{}", a.addOne());
}
```

I expect the output of 6, but this code does not compile:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `T`
 --> src/main.rs:7:16
  |
7 |         self.n + 1
  |         ------ ^ - {integer}
  |         |
  |         T
  |
  = note: `T` might need a bound for `std::ops::Add`
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be when `T` is a `String`?

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with the help of the `num` crate:

```
use num::One; // 0.2.0
use std::ops::Add;

struct Foo<T: Add<T>> {
    n: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T> + One,
{
    fn addOne(self) -> T {
        self.n + One::one()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo { n: 5 };
    println!("{}", a.addOne());
}
```

You can do the same by implementing your own `One` as an exercise, but it requires a lot of boilerplate code:

```
trait One {
    fn one() -> Self;
}

// Now do the same for the rest of the numeric types such as u8, i8, u16, i16, etc
impl One for i32 {
    fn one() -> Self {
       1
    }
}
```